# Manutenção e recuperação de URLs de serviços

Tags: .net, configuração

Estou trabalhando em um projeto Web Forms que possui uma DLL, e nessa DLL há referências a serviços externos. Temos 3 ambientes (desenvolvimento, homologação e produção) e para cada ambiente há uma URL específica para cada um dos serviços, em sua versão para o respectivo ambiente.

Estou tendo problemas para gerenciar as URLs desses serviços. No projeto WebForms tenho o `web.config` em que posso usar XML Transformations para armazenar conjuntos chave/valor, e isso resolveria meu problema. No entanto, na DLL tenho apenas um arquivo `app.config` e o mesmo não dá suporte a transformations. Qual a forma mais indicada de deixar minha solução adaptada para se integrar ao ambiente correto, baseada apenas na Configuration usada durante o processo de Publish?

Apenas para salientar meu modelo atual: eu crio uma entrada no Web.Config com a URL do serviço

```
<add key="UrlServicoCep" value="http://url_dev/servico.asmx" />
```

Em seguida recupero esse valor e o passo como um parâmetro na instanciação da classe em que o serviço é utilizado:

```
string urlServico = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UrlServicoCep"];
var dao = new CepDAO(urlServico);
```

Resumo: **Quero gerar um pacote para o ambiente desejado (homologação ou produção) e que essa geração do pacote já tenha a URL correta aplicada aos web services que consumo.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> No entanto, na DLL tenho apenas um arquivo app.config e o mesmo não dá suporte a transformations.

Dá sim. Só instalar a seguinte extensão no seu Visual Studio:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/579d3a78-3bdd-497c-bc21-aa6e6abbc859

---

EDIT

Se não quiser usar a extensão, creio que o método já esteja bem próximo do adequado. Eu faria apenas uma pequena modificação:

```
string urlServico = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UrlServicoCep"] ?? "http://url_default/servico.asmx";
var dao = new CepDAO(urlServico);
```

Comment: Mas levando em consideração a limitação nativa de não ter a xml transformation, como você resolveria o problema?

Comment: @TiagoCésarOliveira Sem considerar a extensão, acredito que o seu modo já esteja adequado, com alguns opcionais para segurança. Vou editar a resposta.